# Uploading ionic (cordova) Windows Phone App to Windows store

Tags: windows, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I want to publish windows mobile app but error message is => 
Package acceptance validation error: The Publisher attribute of the Identity element in the app manifest of file CordovaApp.Phone_0.0.1.0_anycpu.appx is CN=$username$, which doesn't match your publisher ID: CN=XXXXX.

I have publisher id. I have paid for a Windows Store account. I can't find publisherID property in config.xml